# Node red result data

Tags: iot, node-red, lorawan

I have a simple question :

Using node-red, I have a result in this format: `[{}]`, but I want it like this `{}`.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: StackOverflow questions should include what you've tried and a description of how it didn't work. Please read the FAQ on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

[{...}] is an array containing an object. {...} is an object. To go from [{}] to {}, simply index the first element like so:

```
result = [{"stuff": "things", ...}];
new_result = result[0];
```

`new_result` is `{"stuff": "things", ...}`

Comment: but the result of your solution is the first character of result, it means "["

Answer (score 1):

You can use the change node to extract the first element from an array using JSONATA.

[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0Lq.png)

e.g.

```
[{"id":"efe073293d865f28","type":"inject","z":"d8cb24f4281c772e","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"[{\"id\":1,\"foo\":\"bar\"}]","payloadType":"json","x":190,"y":120,"wires":[["2f3f75244999adeb"]]},{"id":"2f3f75244999adeb","type":"change","z":"d8cb24f4281c772e","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"payload[0]","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":440,"y":120,"wires":[["78bf1271407b0e82"]]},{"id":"78bf1271407b0e82","type":"debug","z":"d8cb24f4281c772e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":690,"y":120,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: thanks @hardillb , to be honest the way that you proposed me works but I have just a little problem, in my data range I have [{xxxxx}, {yyyyy}, {zzzzz}, ... ]. th result of this node is only {xxxxx} since I need all {} either in one message or separately. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at the split node